# Error setting expression X with value [Ljava.lang.String;@......]

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I am getting sometimes and sometimes not weird error:

```
Error setting expression X with value [Ljava.lang.String;@......]
```

It sometimes occurs and sometimes not. It is quiet annoying. The error sometimes comes from this class:

```
package com.coreRestaurant.menuItem;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class MenuItemAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MenuItem>{

    private MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    private final String DATABASE_PROBLEMS = "Error code : Database problems";
    private String json;

    public String execute(){
        MenuItemService itemService = new MenuItemService();
        if(itemService.testDatabaseConnectionU()){
        setJson(new Gson().toJson(itemService.getMenuItemsByMenuId(menuItem.getMenuId()) ));
        }else{
            setErrorToBeSentBackToClientSide(DATABASE_PROBLEMS);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem getModel() {
        return menuItem;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    private void setErrorToBeSentBackToClientSide(String error){

        String errorCode = error;
        setJson(new Gson().toJson(errorCode));

    }
}
```

And then `MenuItem` class:

```
package com.coreRestaurant.menuItem;

public class MenuItem {

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int menuId;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getMenuId() {
        return menuId;
    }
    public void setMenuId(int menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }
    public void setMenuId(MenuItem fromJson) {
        setName(fromJson.getName());
        setPrice(fromJson.getPrice());

    }
}
```

And I am calling those things from PHP file (the two lines do that, but the second one is a worrychild):

```
 $specificMenuJson = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/Core/read?id=' . $menuId);
 $specificMenuItemsJson = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/Core/readMenuItemById?menuId=' . $menuId);
```

It has problem setting the value of `menuId`, but I have getters and setters included. I don't know why it sometimes fails to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the name of the method `setMenuId`

```
public void fromJsonMenuId(MenuItem fromJson) {
    setName(fromJson.getName());
    setPrice(fromJson.getPrice());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

When modeldriven Interceptor calls setMenuId(int menuId) method, it passing an String value to the int menuId argument. Since there is no implicit conversion made by the Interceptor from String to int

Comment: are you sure? because the first one is not calling MenuItemAction class but MenuAction class which is not included here. Both of these are calling different ActionClasses.

Comment: ok i will check it out. But it is still strange because most of the times it has been working (at least on localhost) and there it has been passing string to int. I dont know why it is doing it but I try to the modding and see the result. I'll let u know if it worked. Anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: okay tried that but still not working. Changed my menuId to String but not working

Comment: on which line you are getting this error.Run in Debug mode and provide the stack trace.